# How to Django query only latest rows

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django models:

```
class Amount(Model):
    hold_fk = ForeignKey(to=Hold)
    creation_time = DateTimeField()

class Hold(Model):
    group_fk = ForeignKey(to=Group)

class Group(Model):
    pass
```

Each `Group` has multiple holds and each `Hold` has multiple amounts.

I have a Group instance. I want to get all the amounts that belong to the group, but I only want the latest one from each hold (newest creation time).

How do I accomplish that using Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
group = Group.objects.first()
latest_creation_time_per_hold_name = "latest_creation_time_per_hold"

    latest_amounts_per_hold = Amount.objects.annotate(**{
        latest_creation_time_per_hold_name: Subquery(
            queryset=Amount.objects.filter(**{
                Amount.hold_fk.field.name: OuterRef(Amount.hold_fk.field.name),
            }).order_by(
                "-" + Amount.creation_time.field.name,
            ).values_list(
                Amount.creation_time.field.name,
                flat=True,
            )[:1],
            output_field=DateTimeField(),
        ),
    }).filter(**{
        Amount.creation_time.field.name: F(latest_creation_time_per_hold_name),
        "__".join((
            Amount.hold_fk.field.name,
            Hold.group_fk.field.name,
        )): group,
    })
```

Note that the list slicing `[:1]` is used to keep the result as a queryset. Things like `first` or `latest` will try to execute the query and fail do to the`OuterRef`.